# simple php define in drupal template

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have next to no experience with php as a language, and am running it a little problem in producing a Drupal theme. What I need is to execute a function once, that will return a Boolean, then use that Boolean throughout the template.

Here is what I have so far:

`html.tpl.php`->

```
<?php 

   function testMobile(){
       return false;
   }

   define('isMobile', testMobile());

?>

...

<?php 
    if(!isMobile){
        echo '<h1>NOT MOBILE</h1>';
    }else{
        echo '<h1>IS MOBILE</h1>';
    }
?>
```

`page.tpl.php`->

```
<?php 
   if(!isMobile){
       echo '<h1>IS DESKTOP</h1>';
   }else{
       echo '<h1>NOT DESKTOP</h1>';
   }
?>
```

In the drupal output I get this ->

```
NOT MOBILE

NOT DESKTOP
```

along with this error message:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant isMobile - assumed 'isMobile' in include() (line 77 of /Users/#/#/#/sites/all/themes/#/templates/page.tpl.php).
```

what am I doing wrong here? How can I most easily achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the defined variable is falling out of the scope of the template file. You can simply solve this by using a session variable.

Below is a code sample ...

```
session_start(); // not necessary with drupal
$_SESSION['isMobile'] = testMobile();

function testMobile(){
   return false;
}
```

In your template you can add following...

```
<?php 
   if(!$_SESSION['isMobile']){
       echo '<h1>IS DESKTOP</h1>';
   }else{
       echo '<h1>NOT DESKTOP</h1>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define variable in `template.php` in `hook_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook)`.

So `template.php` can looks follow way:

```
function testMobile(){
  return false;
}

function YOURTHEME_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $vars['isMobile'] = testMobile();
}
```

And `page.tpl.php`

```
<?php 
   if(!$isMobile){
       echo '<h1>IS DESKTOP</h1>';
   }else{
       echo '<h1>NOT DESKTOP</h1>';
   }
?>
```